# React document not viewing using ReactDocViewer using blob storage link

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-doc-viewer

I am trying to open up a blob storage stored document on browser , bue grtting below error

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fMkgf.png)

The blob storage code that i use is below:

import DocViewer, { DocViewerRenderers } from '@cyntler/react-doc-viewer';

```
const byte = base64ToArrayBuffer(arr);
const type = getMIMEType('docx');
const blob = new Blob([byte], { type });
const aElement = document.createElement('a');
aElement.setAttribute('download', 'Shreya');
const href = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
```

This creats a blob storage link

```
const docs = [
 {
  uri: href,
  fileType: type
 }
];

<DocViewer documents={docs} pluginRenderers={DocViewerRenderers} />
```

I tried using this url with iframes but getting the same error